# IOS app crash when created from Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines

I am working on a Xamarin.IOS project. Everything works fine when build(IPA) is created from **Visual studio**, but when i compile the same project from **Xamarin studio** IPA crashes giving JIT compile method exception.

```
products.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AG_Product>(prod.ToString()));

Exception Attempting to JIT compile method 'Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory:CreateDefaultConstructor<object> (System.Type)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
```

I am using VSTS for creating a build in mac build agent, so i need it to work. I have to compile the code using Xamarin Studio create IPA run test cases then publish the IPA.

Comment: I think this is a issue related to "Limited Generics Support". please have a look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/ and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/under_the_hood/api_design/nsobject_generics/

Comment: I understand the limitations. the thing i can't understand is, why every thing works fine when build from VS and crashes when build from Xamarin Studio.

Comment: What is the target machine used when building using VS? Isn't it the same Mac OS computer?

Comment: Yes it is, but VS compiles the code and create a build, But when XS does it IPA crashes, Same code. everything is same. I think some project configuration is automatically changed when opening project in XS. I don't know what change is happening.

Comment: Try  to unchecked the LLVM optimizing compiler option.